# 'while' loop runs when code entered above to weed out certain inputs

Tags: python, while-loop

I can't figure out why my code isn't weeding out any floats and is letting them run in the while loop (which then screws up the code). Is there something I can do to safeguard the 'while loop' - make it not run whenever a float is put in the input?

Here is my code:

```
if not a.isdigit() and int(a) < 0 and not b.isdigit() and int(b) < 0 :
     print("Invalid input")     
 else :
     count = 1
     while count < int(b) :
         c = count * int(a)
         print('{} * {} = {}'.format(count, a, c))
         count = count + 1
     c = int(a) * int(b)
     print('{} * {} = {}'.format(b, a, c))
```

Comment: what are examples of a,b?

Comment: a = input("Enter the number for 'num': ")
b = input("Enter the number for 'N': ")

Comment: the aim is to produce a bunch of outputs like this:

Comment: 1 * 4 = 4
2 * 4 = 8
3 * 4 = 12
4 * 4 = 16
5 * 4 = 20
6 * 4 = 24
7 * 4 = 28
8 * 4 = 32
9 * 4 = 36
10 * 4 = 40

Comment: but obviously there is spaces

Comment: You only spit out an error if everything that could possibly go wrong went wrong, rather than if something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change those `and`s to `or`s so that any of those conditions (`a.isdigit()`, `int(a) < 0`, etc.) being true will result in avoiding the loop.

Comment: You are an absolute Jet Mate!!!! I love you :D i spent way too long trying alternative code

Answer (score 0):

Check upfront whether b has decimals:

```
if round(b)==b:
```